# Add admin bar link to edit author

Tags: functions, admin, author, admin-bar, author-template

I am trying to allow my editors and admins to click to "Edit Author" as they would "Edit Post" or "Edit [Custom Post Type]" from the admin bar when they are on a page like /authors/jdoe

(Note: I do `$wp_rewrite->author_base = 'people'` so that my addresses are /people/jdoe ... not sure if that creates any potential issues.)

I tried to do this through functions but later read that functions.php is processed too early to get the current template or any variables or IDs from the page content.

```
function add_author_edit_link( $wp_admin_bar ) {
if ( is_page_template('author.php') ) {
  $args = array(
    'id' => 'author-edit',
    'title' => __( 'Edit Person' ),
    'href' => '/wp-admin/user-edit.php?user_id=' . $user->ID
  );
$wp_admin_bar->add_node($args);
  } // if is_page_template author
}
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'add_author_edit_link', 500 );
```

Not sure how to approach this but will appreciate any thoughts.

I guess I could try to put it into the page content for certain roles only, but is there no easier way to add something like it to the admin bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this modification of your code:

```
function add_author_edit_link( $wp_admin_bar )
{
    if ( is_author() && current_user_can( 'add_users' ) )
    {
        $args = array(
           'id'    => 'author-edit',
           'title' => __( 'Edit Author' ),
           'href'  => admin_url( sprintf( 
               'user-edit.php?user_id=%d',
               get_queried_object_id() 
           ) )
        );
        $wp_admin_bar->add_node($args);
  } 
}

add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'add_author_edit_link', 99 );
```

where we use the `get_queried_object_id()` function to get the author id.

Notice that you can use the [`admin_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url) to get the url to the backend.

I use [`is_author()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_author) here instead of `is_page_template( 'author.php' )`.

This *Edit Author* link might not be relevant for users that can't modify other users, so I added the `current_user_can( 'add_users' )` check. I couldn't find the  `edit_users` *capability* so I used `add_users` instead.

Comment: There are meta caps `'edit_users'` and `'edit_user'` (see `map_meta_cap()` in "wp-includes/capabilities.php") so I think you should be able to use `current_user_can( 'edit_user', get_queried_object_id() )` here...

Comment: thanks @bonger for checking it further - yesterday evening I could only check the Codex page on capabilities and not dig further on that ;-)

Comment: Thank you! This works for me. I was confused about using is_author() because I wasn't sure if that would be _me_ or the _author on the page_. This clarifies it.

Answer (score 1):

You might try this:

```
function add_author_edit_link( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    if ( is_author() && current_user_can( 'add_users' )) {
        $currentUserID = get_current_user_id();
        $args = array(
            'id' => 'author-edit',
            'title' => __( 'Edit Person' ),
            'href' => '/wp-admin/user-edit.php?user_id=' . $currentUserID
        );
        $wp_admin_bar->add_node($args);
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'add_author_edit_link', 500 );
```

Comment: This works for me. Thank you! I expect to see someone add it to a list of "top __ wp admin bar hacks" or something.